# Click event not working when notification clicked

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Following is the code of messaging service.

```
public class FireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService  {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
private static int count = 0;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message TITLE: " + 
 remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message BODY: " + 
 remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message DATA: " + 
remoteMessage.getData().toString());


    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
            remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), 
 remoteMessage.getData());

}

//This method is only generating push notification
private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody, 
 Map<String, String> row) {
    // PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
    PendingIntent contentIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, 
  LoginActivity.class), 0);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = 
   RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
 NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
  R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) 
  getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build());

    count++;

}
}
```

I am new to programming so please ignore the mistakes.Also in above code it dosen't notify when the app is in foreground.So there are two queries one is that when notification is clicked it dosen't trigger LoginActivity and other is App is not notifying when in foreground.

Comment: Is `LoginActivity` your launcher activity? Have you registered the service `FireBaseMessagingService` in the manifest? Are you testing your code in device with Android Oreo?

Comment: Do you really have a reference from an `activity` or a `context`?

Comment: @NabinBhandariYes I have registered it in manifest and testing in Oreo

Comment: @jake I didnt get you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing below line
                **

> notificationManager.contentIntent = contentIntent;

**

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) 
  getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.contentIntent = contentIntent;
        notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

what type of notification you are using?
inside your notification you just add the click action method and sent it

'

```
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="given click ation name" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>'
```

this is better way to iintent to your class